# riddle about  who 2 people in the torah are

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, riddle, family-members

Name 2 figures in the Torah that their mother is their sister, their aunts and uncles are dead, and their father is their grandfather.

Comment: we need more riddles on mi.yodea!

Answer (score 11):

Papa Smurf's answer is close; I think it's Lot's daughters' sons - Moav (ancestor of the Moabites) and Ben-Ammi (ancestor of the Ammonites).

- Their mothers are their sisters - because their father is Lot, the father of their respective mothers.
- Their aunts and uncles are dead - because all of them were destroyed with the rest of the inhabitants of Sodom.
- Their father is their grandfather - as above: he's their father as well as their (maternal) grandfather.

Comment: Yep. Looks like you got it

Comment: But of course not all their aunts and uncles are dead. I mean, they are _now_, but not when they were living: each had one living aunt(-cum-half-sister).

Comment: Oh, and another living aunt: _Sara_. (She was a sister of _Lot_, according to _M'gila_ 14:1.) And hence a living uncle (by marriage), _Avraham_.

Answer (score 3):

Lots 2 daughters

Comment: Really? Can you explain how each part of the riddle applies to them?

Comment: So close, papa.